# Enable voice dictation for textfield without default keyboard in tvOS

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uisearchbar, tvos, custom-keyboard

We need to design a search bar with custom keyboard in tvOS. Keyboard that displays only particular keys within the particular area of the page and not full screen.Something like the keyboard below:
[image]

As tvOS doesn't allow such customisation on the default search keyboard, we used a textfield and designed the custom keyboard using collection view.

We are able to show the text in the textfield using the custom keyboard and need to bring the voice dictation input also in place, ie, trigger voice dictation when user do long press on siri button when textfield is in focus.

I have checked multiple apps in tvOS and not able to see this voice dictation enabled for the custom keyboard textfields. For eg, the youtube sign-in page with custom keyboard.

Is there any way, we can achieve the voice dictation input in textfield inline(same behaviour of voice search in default searchBar) without enabling the default keyboard in tvOS?